# MDC web components: mdc-dialog doesn't close properly sometimes

Tags: javascript, web, material-design, material-components, material-components-web

I use MDC-Web components. I'm opening and closing a dialog programmatically, but sometimes it doesn't close. I don't know if I am doing the right way in order to close the dialog.

```
closeDialog('dialog_gui');

function closeDialog(elementId){
    let dialog = new mdc.dialog.MDCDialog(document.getElementById(elementId));
    dialog.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function creates the new instance of MDCDialog every time dialog gets closed. You should store the instance of dialog outside the closing function:

```
const dialog = new mdc.dialog.MDCDialog(document.getElementById('dialog_gui'));

function closeDialog() {
  // some stuff
  dialog.close();
}

closeDialog();
```

Also, you can close dialog without extra function, just using MDCDialog's `close()` method:

```
const dialog = new mdc.dialog.MDCDialog(document.getElementById('dialog_gui'));

dialog.close();
```

Here is [the Codepen example](https://codepen.io/rustemgareev/pen/MrNdpz?editors=1010) where dialog will be opened, and then closed after 3 seconds.